# Group by and outer apply not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

in the following query I want to make some grouping but don't want to include some fields:

```
SELECT C.id_credito, SUM(M.monto), M.fecha_mov, ISNULL(tg.nombre, tp.NombComp) AS Acreditados
FROM movimientos AS M
JOIN acreditados AS A ON A.id_acreditado = M.id_acreditado
JOIN creditos AS C ON C.id_credito = A.id_credito
JOIN cargos AS CA ON CA.id_movimiento = M.id_movimiento
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 G.nombre FROM grupos G JOIN agrupaciones AG on AG.id_grupo = G.id_grupo WHERE AG.id_acreditado = A.id_acreditado) tg
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 P.nombres+' '+P.apellido_paterno+' '+P.apellido_materno AS NombComp  FROM personas P WHERE P.id_persona = A.id_persona) tp
WHERE M.tipo_mov = 0 AND M.fecha_mov < DATEADD(day, 14, GETDATE()) AND CA.tipo_cargo = 0
GROUP BY C.id_credito, M.fecha_mov
```

The fields I don't want to include are tg.nombre and tp.NombComp because when I include them the fields are not grouped correctly. However if I don't put them in GROUP BY clause I get the following error:

*Column 'tp.NombComp' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

Can you help me please? I'm using SQL server 2008 express

EDIT: I'll show some examples, if I "ISNULL(tg.nombre, tp.NombComp) AS Acreditados" is removed from the query the grouping works fine, as you can see first groups by id_credito and then by fecha_mov

```
id_credito monto        fecha_mov
84     1875.00  2012-06-07
89     1875.00   2012-06-11
94     739.58   2012-06-11
85     2338.00  2012-06-14
.....
```

But If I the previous fields are added to GROUP BY clause, grouping doesn't work as expected.

```
SELECT C.id_credito, SUM(M.monto), M.fecha_mov, ISNULL(tg.nombre, tp.NombComp) AS Acreditados
FROM movimientos AS M
JOIN acreditados AS A ON A.id_acreditado = M.id_acreditado
JOIN creditos AS C ON C.id_credito = A.id_credito
JOIN cargos AS CA ON CA.id_movimiento = M.id_movimiento
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 G.nombre FROM grupos G JOIN agrupaciones AG on AG.id_grupo = G.id_grupo WHERE AG.id_acreditado = A.id_acreditado) tg
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 P.nombres+' '+P.apellido_paterno+' '+P.apellido_materno AS NombComp  FROM personas P WHERE P.id_persona = A.id_persona) tp
WHERE M.tipo_mov = 0 AND M.fecha_mov < DATEADD(day, 14, GETDATE()) AND CA.tipo_cargo = 0
GROUP BY C.id_credito, M.fecha_mov, tg.nombre, tp.NombComp
```

```
id_credito   monto      fecha_mov       Acreditados
84       625.00 2012-06-07  Politos
84       729.17 2012-06-07  Politos
84       520.83 2012-06-07  Politos
85       584.50 2012-06-14  Acuna
85       584.50 2012-06-14  Acuna
85       584.50 2012-06-14  Acuna
85       584.50 2012-06-14  Acuna
86       584.50 2012-06-14  Estrellas de Cuatro Vientos
86       584.50 2012-06-14  Estrellas de Cuatro Vientos
86       584.50 2012-06-14  Estrellas de Cuatro Vientos
86       584.50 2012-06-14  Estrellas de Cuatro Vientos
...
```

Comment: group by will give you one row per groupe so witch tg.nombre and tp.NombComp values do you wante to use min max avg...?

Comment: Without those values in the group by clause the query groups correctly but If i added rows are not grouped. I don't want to perform aggregate functions on these fields just show them

Comment: As anouar204 asked, do you want the min, the max?  Or, are you looking to concatenate the values together in a string?

Comment: Can you give some data sample?

Comment: I edited my question to show you some examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  SELECT C.id_credito, SUM(M.monto), M.fecha_mov,  
  ISNULL(min(tg.nombre),min(tp.NombComp)) AS Acreditados
  .
  . 
  .
  GROUP BY C.id_credito, M.fecha_mov
```